# Show profile fields depending on the profile users role

Tags: entities, users

We are using profile2 to display users listed on our site which has different member levels. Is there an easy way to hide certain fields based on the profile2 users role. We still like them to enter the information when they complete their profile, but we only want to show this information to other visitors when the profile user has a specific member level.

If this can be done for fields, can this be done for views as well? Bascically show or not show a specific view on the user profile page, based on the users role?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)?

Comment: I have installed Field Permissions, but correct me if I am wrong, field permissions works on the permissions of the user that is currently viewing the page. What I like to achieve is that if an anonymous user views the profile page of a basic member, I like to hide certain fields (e.g. contact details). If the same user views the profile page of a premium members I like this information to be displayed.